# Stitches theme not updating Radix UI's Dropdown.Content component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, darkmode

so I am currently working with the `stitches` styling library and the `radix-ui` library. I am using the theme feature (darkTheme/lightTheme).

It all works perfectly in updating all but one of the `radix-ui` components.

The `Dropdown.Content` doesn't get updated right and I don't understand why. I am currently passing in a `$backgroundColor` to the styles and instead of it changing depending on the theme, it sticks to the color from the default theme.

This is the code from my `styles.ts` file:

```
export const DropdownContent = styled(DropdownMenu.Content, {
  background: '$backgroundColor',
  border: '2px solid $borderColor',
)},
```

This is a snippet from my `stitches.config.ts` file:

```
export const {
  styled,
  css,
  globalCss,
  keyframes,
  theme,
  createTheme,
  config,
} = createStitches({
  theme: {
    colors: {
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      borderColor: '#E5E8EB',
    },
    space: {},
    fonts: {},
  },
  media: {},
  utils: {},
});

export const darkTheme = createTheme({
  colors: {
    backgroundColor: '#141416',
    borderColor: '#353945',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the content is rendered directly in the `body` tag through a React `Portal`, a default Radix behavior. Try setting `open={true}` on the `Select` and inspect the content elements to see for yourself.

You're most likely adding the dark theme class somewhere along your component tree, i.e. on your `App` component. That will not work for elements outside of that tree, for instance ones rendered in the `body` tag through a portal.

You need to apply the dark theme class to your `body` tag, like this:

```
const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(true);
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const { classList } = document.body;
    if (darkTheme) classList.add(darkThemeCssClass);
    else classList.remove(darkThemeCssClass);
}, [darkTheme]);
```

This will allow the theme-dependent styling to be applied to all elements on the page, not just ones in your component tree.